# Subdividing scale bar segments using QGIS

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale-bar

How can I subdivide the scale bar segments in smaller subsegments?

I want to style my scale bar like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a few steps involved:

---

1. Create your first scalebar showing kilometers and set the relevant options:

   [image: First scalebar]

---

2. Select the first scalebar and copy/paste it below the original and set the relevant options:

   [image: Second scalebar]

---

3. For the copied scalebar, set its `Font colour` to have an **opacity** of 0%:

   ```
   Item Properties > Fonts and colours > Font colour
   ```

   [image: Set opacity]

---

4. Move the copied scalebar and align it to match the original scalebar. Select both these scalebars and group them:

   [image: Group items]

---

5. You should hopefully have a scalebar with subdivided segments:

   [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, but this I already did. I thought about grouping two differently styled scale bars with different settings in unit and segment menu. But this seems not to be very serious.

Comment: You could [request](https://hub.qgis.org/) this feature to be added in the newer versions of QGIS. You will have to register first before posting requests/bugs etc.

Answer (score 5):

The feature is available in the current QGIS Master 3.13 and in the forthcoming release of QGIS 3.14:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

See https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36131 and https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36222

Answer (score -4):

In arcgis, you can add scale bars with segments by editing its division properties. You can follow this guide

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/layouts/scale-bars.htm

Which mentions

- Adjust number of divisions—Preserves the division value and tries to preserve the scale bar width by adjusting the number of divisions.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This doesn't answer the question, which specifies QGIS.  Since we require those asking questions to choose a software platform, it's only fair that we make Answers honor that choice.