# Scale bar with different sized segments in QGIS

Tags: qgis, scale-bar

Is it possible to divide a QGIS scalebar into different sized segments like the one in the example given, and show the relative labels?

[image]

Comment: Check this : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/123969/is-it-possible-to-subdivide-scale-bar-segments-in-qgis

Comment: While related, I don't think it is a duplicate as the linked post refers to subdivisions (for the entire scalebar length) while this post is about adding some smaller segments (for just part of the scalebar length)

Comment: @JGH Yes, right I would like to divide the scalebar into different sized segments with the relative unit like in the example. Maybe this is possible in Arcgis or in Mapinfo but not in QGIS. The solution posted is interesting although time-consuming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your scale made to be used one time only ?

If so, you can achieve the look you want by manually putting two scales (or more) on top of each other to represent the changes in the segments sizes (and in the units too if you want).

[image]

Here, the two scales are aligned on the left and top sides. One is two kilometers long, in the back and the other one is 0.5 kilometers long, in front.

To get the result you are looking for, I used three (!) scale bars.
[image]

The first one is 20 kilometers long in four segment of 5 kilometers and 'km' as a unit, for the text. The black and white colors are reversed.

The second one is 5 kilometers long in four sections of 1.25 kilometers and no text. To remove the text, set the text opacity to 0.

The third scale is 2.5 kilometers long in one section only, in white color, and no unit.
And, I set the three scale bars objects in a specific order, from top to bottom : 2-3-1.
That's why my method is not suitable for a daily use...

It might be possible to set rules to adapt the length of all the scales for each change of the map scale and keep the same look.

Comment: Thank you, this is the result I wanted, although, as you said, it can be useful just once since it is time-consuming. So I suppose there are no options to do it quickly in QGIS

Answer (score 3):

You can get close to your example by adding "left" segments, i.e. the number of subdivision of the length of **one** right segment. Let's note that the `0` remains at it position, so it is now more or less in the middle of the scalebar, and there is no easy way to use a different scale unit for the left segments

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I already knew this solution but the scalebar with this configuration seems a bit strange to me and it is not possible to add the minor units